# How to build geom_tile/rect boxes with gradient fill and points/lines on top for factor x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm rather confused by this. I want to display the following data in the following way:
[image: The chart I think I want to make]

The chart is supposed to convey the historical bounds of the different data sets while also letting me highlight the last three periods of observations. If there's a better chart for this, please share. If not, then how would I make this chart work in ggplot2?

I've tried using `geom_rect` and can't get it to work for factor data so I've been pinning my hopes to `geom_tile`, which looks promising. But I always end up with cryptic errors. Let me demonstrate:

```
# set the seed so we all have the same data
set.seed(20180702)

# the data for the tiles of the plot
tileData <-
    data.frame(
        Factor = as.factor( c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3") ),
        Heights = c(2, 5, 3)
    )

# sample data we'll want to chart
exampleFrame <-
    data.frame(
        Period = as.factor(rep(c("first", "second", "third"), n = 3)),
        Factor = as.factor(rep(c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3"), each = 3)),
        Data = unlist(lapply(tileData[["Heights"]],
                             function(height) rnorm(3, 0, height)))
    )

# create the plot object with our sample data
ggplot(exampleFrame, aes(x = Factor, y = Data, col = Period)) +
    # add the points for each data point
    geom_point() +
    # now, attempt to add the tiles with a gradient color
    geom_tile(data = tileData,
              mapping = aes(x = Factor, y = 0, height = Heights*2,
              col = NULL, alpha = 0.5)) +
    # this does nothing (??)
    scale_fill_gradient2()
```

And here is output:

[image: GGplot from code example]

As you can see, the gradient is not applied. Also of note, running the code in the console gives the warning: `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: height` when it clearly does implement the tile height based on the data. Do you know how to square this circle and also clean up the legend?

Comment: You haven't actually set a fill aesthetic and I can't tell what you actually want the fill mapped to, can you clarify? The legend will be cleaner if you move `colour` and `alpha` outside of the `aes()` in `geom_tile`, they're fixed aesthetics so you don't want them in `aes()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've focused just on how to do this exact image rather than on whether there's a better visualization.

First thing you were doing wrong is you weren't mapping `fill=` to anything for the tiles.  That's why it was grey.

Then the tricky thing is that you can't have graduated "fill" of a rectangle in `ggplot2` (my understand is that this is a limitation of the underlying `grid` system).  So you need to make quite a contrived version of your `tileData` object that lets you in fact draw many rectangles of different fills to give the impression of a single gradated fill rectangle.

Here's what I came up with:

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

# set the seed so we all have the same data
set.seed(20180702)

# the data for the tiles of the plot
tileData <-
  data.frame(
    Factor = as.factor( rep(c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3") , each = 100)),
    Height = c(seq(from = -2, to = 2, length.out = 100),
                seq(from = -5, to = 5, length.out = 100),
                seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 100)),
    Gradation = abs(seq(from = -1, to =1 , length.out = 100)))
)



# sample data we'll want to chart
exampleFrame <-
  data.frame(
    Period = as.factor(rep(c("first", "second", "third"), n = 3)),
    Factor = as.factor(rep(c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3"), each = 3)),
    Data = unlist(lapply(c(2, 5, 3),
                         function(height) rnorm(3, 0, height)))
  )

# define the half-width of the rectangles
r <- 0.4

ggplot() +
  # add the background first or it over-writes the lines
  geom_rect(data = tileData,
            mapping = aes(xmin = as.numeric(Factor) - r, 
                          xmax = as.numeric(Factor) + r,
                          ymin = Height - 0.1, 
                          ymax = Height + 0.1,
                          fill = Gradation)) +
  # add the lines for each data point
  geom_segment(data = exampleFrame, 
               aes(x = as.numeric(Factor) - r * 1.1,
                   xend = as.numeric(Factor) + r * 1.1,
                   y = Data, yend = Data,
                   col = Period),
               size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradient2("Historic range\nof data", low = "white", high = "lightblue") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("first" = "hotpink", "second" = "darkgreen", "third" = "darkblue")) +
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = unique(as.numeric(exampleFrame$Factor)), labels = levels(exampleFrame$Factor)) +
  theme_minimal()
```